# How to indent multiple lines in nano

Tags: nano, indentation

Selecting lines in nano can be achieved using `Esc+A`. With multiple lines selected, how do I then indent all those lines at once?

Comment: Highlighting is working now by just using `Shift` +  `Arrow-Up` or `Arrow-Down` at least since Nano version: `2.9.1`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Once you have selected the block, you can indent it using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + `}` (not the key, but whatever key combination is necessary to produce a closing curly bracket).

Comment: I am trying this without success on OSX Mavericks. Instead pressing alt+} results in an opening (or closing depending on whether shift is held down at the same time) quote character being inserted.

Comment: @Ben It works for me, perhaps your terminal emulator or window manager is eating the meta key? I don't know about how the OSX terminal works, though.

Comment: @Ben From a quick Google it seems that the Mac terminal is the culprit, see here: http://blog.remibergsma.com/2012/01/30/alt-key-aan-de-praat-in-osx-terminal/ (for future readers, the solution: Terminal > Preferences > Settings > Keyboard > Check "Use option as meta key")

Comment: Thanks for your help. With the setting change for terminal, it now works as you described.

Comment: @Ben You can select lines with Alt+A now. Alt+x and Esc+x are the same thing.

Comment: @Kartik That's not always true. Escape emulation is a function of some terminal emulators, but not all.

Comment: ```Alt``` + ```}``` didn't work for me, could be my putty settings, however ```Alt``` + ```Shift``` + ```{``` did!

Comment: Is there an inverse equivalent to unindent a block of lines?

Comment: @David `Alt + {` :-)

Comment: none of these worked for me, am on linux debian jessie

Comment: For some reason on my keyboard, this only works with the left Alt key but not the Alt key on the right side. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @52d6c6af: Default assignment of the "meta" key (`M`) in `nano` or mac is the `esc` key.

Answer (score 12):

So the full procedure to indent a bunch of lines:

1. <kbd>**↑**</kbd> Go to the first line
2. <kbd>**Alt-A**</kbd> or <kbd>Option-A</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to start selecting - you'll see `[ Mark Set ]`
3. <kbd>**↓**</kbd> Go under the last line
4. <kbd>**Alt-Shift-}**</kbd> or <kbd>Option-Shift-}</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>}</kbd> to **indent**
5. <kbd>**Alt-Shift-{**</kbd> or <kbd>Option-Shift-{</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>{</kbd> to **outdent**
6. <kbd>**Alt-A**</kbd> or <kbd>Option-A</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to unselect - you'll see `[ Mark Unset ]`

By the way, if you think **4 spaces** are beautiful and tabs are [evil](https://youtu.be/SsoOG6ZeyUI):

1. `nano ~/.nanorc` or `sudo nano ~root/.nanorc` or `sudo nano /etc/.nanorc`
2. ```
   set tabsize 4
   set tabstospaces
   ```
3. Of course you have to close and reopen nano for these settings to take effect.

These settings will modify the behavior of alt-shift-}/{ to indent/outdent 4 spaces. Otherwise the default behavior is to insert/remove tabs.

Comment: `Option-Shift-{` and `Option-Shift-}` is working for me

Answer (score 4):

If you're using macOS and haven't reset your meta key in the terminal, the command for this will be <kbd>Esc</kbd>+`}`

Comment: and Esc + { respectively for reverse direction

Answer (score 0):

To indent mulitple lines for Mac users :

- <kbd>ESC</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to set a mark for multiple lines selection, then
- <kbd>ESC</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>)</kbd> to produce a close bracket.
- Type <kbd>ESC</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to unselect.